# Фреймворк для создания простых текстовых редакторов для web

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, framework

Мне нужен текстовый редактор для моего веб-приложения. Многофункциональность не требуется.

Кто-нибудь знает какие-либо фреймворки для создания текстовых редакторов для web?

Я слышал про draft js, но он предназначен для работы с React js, я же разрабатываю свое приложение на нативном javascript, поэтому draft js не вариант.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: ckeditor, tinymce

Comment: https://quilljs.com/